# Does the introduction of elections and other democratic institutions contribute to social disruptions and chaos in a country with a weak state?

Tags: election, democracy, liberalism, political-transitions, authoritarianism

I am conducting a research on a historical period in Iran in which a short period of premature democratic rule by a government with low state capabilities led to social disruptions and chaos and eventually to a prolonged period of authoritarian rule that was able to concentrate power in state apparatuses. Can we find a larger worldwide trend hence a wider theory of premature democratization here?

Comment: What is your "short period of premature democratic rule"?

Comment: How can you ascertain that the democratic experience is what led to troubles rather that other reasons ? Anyway, possibly relevant is the aftermath of Algerian legislative election in 1991 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991_Algerian_legislative_election

Comment: @MartinSchröder I mean the Constitutional regime between 1909 _ 1921.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_Constitutional_Revolution

Comment: @Evargalo Many historians including Abrahamian agree that the main reasons for the success of subsequent coup by Reza Pahlavi was lack of a powerful government and disorder across the country.

Comment: There is definitely a worldwide trend, but it's a question is there a theory describing it..

Comment: The problem with such a theory is that it could devolve into circular logic. "Democracy in A failed because it was a weak state?" And how do you decide that it was a weak state? "Because democracy did fail."

Comment: I want to argue that the German state between 1945 and 1949 was extremely weak (i.e. non-existant; order was kept by military occupiers) but upon introduction of elections and democratic institutions in 1949 there were no social disruptions or chaos – unless you count the disruption that most citizens got far wealthier than they had been or had had a chance of becoming prior to the war.

Comment: Russia post-1990.

Comment: @SJuan76 Weakness of the state can be defined as inability to collect taxes, provide public goods and so on. But I argue that a weak state if democratized would probably lead to failed state. Hence, democracy should come after the first steps of development are realized.